# Boxing Unboxing in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to use wrapper class and primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type)
>   [What is boxing and unboxing and what are the trade offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs)

Boxing basically converts primitive type to its corresponding reference type. But when do we need Boxing? Whether Wrapper class and Boxing do the same job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoboxing/unboxing is a pure convenience feature that allows you to assign values of  a primitive type a reference of a wrapper class and vice versa, with the compiler automatically adding the code to convert between the two.

Comment: really confusing then what is wrapper class? I need to know the difference b/w wrapper class & boxing

Comment: @Sumithra: `java.lang.Integer` is a wrapper class. Autoboxing is the language mechanism that allows you to say `Integer i = 5;` instead of `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);` or `Integer i = new Integer(5);` - and "Boxing" isn't an expression typically used, except perhaps as a shortening of "Autoboxing".

Comment: Boxing uses wrapper objects to box values rit?

Comment: Thanks Michael!!!I understand it now