# Memory allocation/reference comparison for ints and Integers

Tags: java

With the following:

```
String a = new String("test");
String b = "test";
System.out.println(a == b); //false
```

We get false, since `String a` is an object, so `a` points to a different location in memory than the string literal, `b`.  I wanted to see how this worked for `int` and `Integer`:

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
int y =5;
System.out.println(x == y); //true
```

I though that `x.equals(y)` would be true, but `x == y` would be false as it is in the case with `Strings`.  I understand that we compare `ints` with `==`, but I figured that comparing an `int` to an `Integer` would be different.  Why is this not the case?

I assume that in this case using `==` won't work for comparing references, so how would we do it (not sure if this is practical, but I'd like to know)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of boxing and unboxing in java

> Converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If
>   the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

Autoboxing/unboxing is a pure convenience feature that allows you to assign values of a primitive type a reference of a wrapper class and vice versa, with the compiler automatically adding the code to convert between the two.

[Boxing and unBoxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)  and [**SEE HERE ALSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995267/boxing-unboxing-in-java)