# primitives vs wrapper class initialization

Tags: java

What is the Difference between declaring int's as Below. What are the cases which suits the usage of different Types

```
int i     = 20;
Integer i = 20;
Integer i = new Integer(20);
```

**Please Note** : I have goggled and found that first is going to create primitive int.Second is going to carry out auto boxing and Third is going to create reference in memory.

I am looking for a Scenario which clearly explains when should I use first, second and third kind of integer initialization.Does interchanging the usage is going to have any performance hits

Thanks for Reply.

Comment: related: [When to use wrapper class and primitive type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type), [What is boxing and unboxing and what are the trade offs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs), [New Integer vs valueOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initialization in the 1st case is a simple assignment of a constant value.  Nothing interesting... except that this is a primitive value that is being assigned, and primitive values don't have "identity"; i.e. all "copies" of the `int` value `20` are the same.

The 2nd and 3rd cases are a bit more interesting.  The 2nd form is using "boxing", and is actually equivalent to this:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(20);
```

The [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) method *may* create a new object, or it may return a reference to an object that existed previously.  (In fact, the JLS guarantees that `valueOf` will cache the `Integer` values for numbers in the range -128..+127 ...)

By contrast `new Integer(20)` *always* creates a new object.

This issue with new object (or not) is important if you are in the habit of comparing `Integer` wrapper objects (or similar) using `==`.  In one case `==` may be `true` if you compare two instances of "20".  In the other case, it is guaranteed to be `false`.

The lesson: use `.equals(...)` to compare wrapper types not `==`.

---

On the question of which to use:

- If `i` is `int`, use the first form.
- If `i` is `Integer`, the second form is best ... unless you *need* an object that is `!=` to other instances.  Boxing (or explicitly calling `valueOf`) reduces the amount of object allocation for small values, and is a worthwhile optimization.

Comment: Well said Thanks for Reply

Comment: Integer I is it equal to int i  in terms  of  creation?  Will  Integer I  is  not  created  in  the  heap  memory?  As  I  have  got  Short s=20  and when I compare Integer I==Short s  it  will  give  compile time error but when its int i== Short s its true!!!!! @Stephen C

Comment: @Gpar - 1) Unclear what you are asking  2) Unclear what you are asking. 3) That is not a question.

Comment: @Gpar - Hint: if you want proper answers to your questions then: 1) search StackOverflow to see if they have already been asked and answered, then 2) take the time to write a proper Question.

Answer (score 3):

Primitives will take default values when declared without assignment.

But wrapper classes are reference types, so without assignment they will be `null`. This may cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown if used without assignment.

Answer (score 1):

One such scenario I can think of is when you are mapping DB types in `Hibernate`. If you use Integer you can check for null (assuming the column allows `null` values). If you use primitive and if the value is null in the database, I guess it throws an error.