# How does a float assign with a Float?

Tags: java

Float is an object, float is a variable. And how to a float can assign with a Float.
Thank you!

```
Float F = new Float(3);
float f = F;
```

Comment: read 'wrapper classes'.

Comment: Look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type

Answer (score 5):

That's called [autoboxing/unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). It's a Java feature which allows implicit conversions between primitive types and their corresponding wrapper classes.

**Autoboxing** is when, like in your snippet, a primitive is wrapped into an object. `Unboxing`, viceversa, is the opposite way.

What happens under the hood is something like:

```
float f = 10.0f;
Float fo = new Float(f); // autoboxing
float f2 = fo.floatValue(); // unboxing
```

Comment: Autoboxing doesn't work by converting it to `new Float(...)`, but to `Float.valueOf(...)`.

Comment: @Jesper which is `new Float(f)`, check implementation: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Float.java#Float.valueOf%28float%29

Comment: Yes, but for `Integer` for example, `Integer.valueOf()` does not do `new Integer()` - it has a cache for `Integer` objects with values between -128 and 127.

Answer (score 2):

The `F` object of type `Float` is automatically [unboxed](https://www.google.fr/search?q=java%20unboxing&oq=java%20unboxing&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.2917j0j1&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). What you have in your `f` variable isn't `F` but `F.floatValue()`.