# From C++ to Java (ArrayList of Complex numbers)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a simple question. How can i create by using ArrayList that data structure in Java ?

```
 vector< complex<float> > *v1;
 v1 = new vector< complex<float> >;
```

I tried something like this:

```
ArrayList< Complex<float> > v1;
```

but dont work :/

(I included 'Apache commons math' jar for complex numbers)

Comment: I understand your question though! It's a normal doubt when you start with java. The reason lies in `type erasure`. Any generic type at runtime is converted to `java.lang.Object` and cast at needed times. This can't happen with a primitive type. You'll find plenty of info on that!

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support primitive generics right now (Possibly in Java 11). You will need to use the wrapper class, which will come with a performance hit.

```
List<Complex<Float>> list;
```

You may want to create your own complex number class.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Also, I can't believe that the performance hit is **so** large in boxing and unboxing for almost all operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type