# Hashmap (alternative) with just 1 entry

Tags: java

I've got something set up,
now I want to have a string saved, with an Date attached to it.

```
private HashMap<String, Date> something = new HashMap<String, Date>();
```

The problem I'm having is that I only want 1 thing inside this HashMap, so when I put a new String, Date in, the old one gets removed.

I've got this myself by just calling clear before I add one, but then I came on to a different problem:

```
String current = something.get ????
```

As you see above, I just want to get the 1 entry inside. Without the date.

Is there a better alternative? Or am I seeing something completely wrong?

Comment: Why use a Map if you are just storing one thing? Why not just assign the Date to a variable directly?

Comment: Or make an object just containing your two variables.

Comment: You mean just have the String current and then Date current or something as 2 different variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Pair<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html):

> A convenience class to represent name-value pairs.

```
// The import statement
import javafx.util.Pair;

Pair<String, Date> something = new Pair<>("string1", new Date());
```

And you can use

`something.getKey()` to get the `String`, & `something.getValue()` to get the `Date`.

Comment: Only problem with this, Pairs can only be set in the statement you gave me above right? But I do need to set it more than once...

Comment: @MrDikke No, it's not `final`; you are free to assign a new instance of Pair to your reference at any point in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities to do that. You could just have a `String` and a `Date` variable together with a setter:

```
private String someString;
private Date someDate;

private void setStringDate(String someString, Date someDate) {
    this.someString = someString;
    this.someDate = someDate;
}
```

Another possibility is to encapsulate that functionality in a class:

```
public class StringDate {
    private String someString;
    private Date someDate;

    // setter ... (like above)

    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }

    public Date getSomeDate() {
        return someDate;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you need other Data-structures than `String` and `Date` you could use Generics on your own class to realize that!

Answer (score 0):

It seems `something` should just be a variable that stores a `String,Date` pair. If you don't want to define a tiny class for that, or use two variables, you can use a [Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767321/277304) .