# Java Array pass-by-reference

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have this code:

```
public static int MAX;
public static int MIN;


public static void startGame(){

    MIN = -1;

    MAX = 1;

    int[] randomGridVals = new int[ROWS*COLUMNS];

    fill(randomGridVals);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomGridVals));

    <MORE CODE>
}

private static void fill(int[] randomGridVals) {

    for(int i = 0 ; i < randomGridVals.length; i++)
    {
        int rnd = MIN + (int)(Math.random() * ((MAX - MIN) + 1));

        randomGridVals[i] = rnd;
    }

}
```

I expect that the array is passed by reference and the array have random values in it however when I try to print it its empty. Why is this happening ?

Comment: What are the values of MIN and MAX?

Comment: Sorry, they are basically the range for the random function. I updated the code

Comment: Your code look, and works fine for me.  I used MAX = 222 and MIN = 111.

Comment: What are the values of ROWS and COLUMNS?  (And note that ALL CAPS implies these are constants of some sort.)

Comment: Strange, I will give it a try.

Comment: @HotLicks they are basically specified at the beginning through the GUI to form a grid

Comment: Ahh this is so silly, I assign the values to the ROWS and COLUMNS down so they are null when this part executes. Sorry for this..

Comment: This link has a good explanation which may clarify your doubt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333151/java-how-to-pass-byte-by-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to say for sure from the code you have provided. I would check the value of `ROWS*COLUMNS`. That is probably 0 and thus you create a 0 sized array.

Comment: I am sure the constants are fine since I use them to construct a grid.

Comment: Since the code prints [], that's proof that ROWS*COLUMNS = 0.

Comment: @Cemre - when do you set ROWS and COLUMNS.  They really should be set at declaration, since they are all caps and that means "static final".  My guess is that you set them _after_ running this routine.

Answer (score 2):

[Java is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) [never pass by reference](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html). [It's always pass-by-value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

As for being empty, please post ROWS and COLUMNS or check them.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you defining ROWS and COLUMNS? At least one of them must equal 0, rendering your data structure an int[0].

Since `int` is a primitive type, your array starts out filled with 0s. Since arrays can't be resized, and Arrays.toString will print every cell (it won't just skip 0s- 0 is usually pretty important in an `int[]`, for one thing!), this result cannot be an artifact of your array not being written into. It must have been initialized to length 0, and that means that `ROWS * COLUMNS == 0`. Check the value of `ROWS`, of `COLUMNS`, and also their types- surprising types other than int might in rare cases cause this, but the 0 is more likely.